# Zend_Db does not delete table row

Tags: database, zend-framework, frameworks, adapter

Does anyone know, if there is a bug in CRUD in delete operations.
DB Adapter:

```
$this->_db = Zend_Registry::get("db");
```

I do like this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM premium_items WHERE id = '$id'";
                    $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($this->_db, $sql); 
                    return $stmt->execute();
```

and

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM premium_items WHERE id = ?";
                $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($this->_db, $sql); 
                return $stmt->execute(array($id));
```

and

```
$this->_db->delete('premium_items', "id = '$id'");
```

Each variant works without any errors but does not do what it has to do.
What can I do in such situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `Zend_Db_Adapter`, try:

```
$this->_db->delete('premium_items', array("id = ?" => $id));
```

or, in this particular case you can do:

```
$this->_db->delete('premium_items', 'id = ' . (int)$id);
```

(but only do this one if you're using an integer and you cast it!)

Comment: Found the solution, everybody was right, one just always has to check if the transaction is committed :(

Answer (score 1):

In your model (Zend_Db_Table_Abstract):

```
$row = $this->find($id)->current();
$row->delete();
```

Or

```
$db = $this->getAdapter();
$db->delete($table, $db->quoteInto("id = ?", $id));
```

Comment: I actually have this already:
`public function __construct(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract $dbTable, $id)
{
 $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
 if ($id) {
  $this->_row = $this->_dbTable->find($id)->current();
 } else {
  $this->_row = $this->_dbTable->createRow();
 }
}`

then

`public function delete()
{
 return $this->_row->delete();
}`

Comment: I already had this probleme, without find any solution with zend_db_table function..
I solve this with my last code